# the usage of scp and ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I'm newbie to Linux and trying to set up a passphrase-less ssh. I'm following the instructions in this link: http://wiki.hands.com/howto/passphraseless-ssh/.

In the above link, it said:"One often sees people using passphrase-less ssh keys for things like cron jobs that do things like this:"

```
scp /etc/bind/named.conf* otherdns:/etc/bind/
ssh otherdns /usr/sbin/rndc reload
```

which is dangerous because the key that's being used here is being offered root write access, when it need not be.

I'm kind of confused by the above commands. 
I understand the usage of scp. But for ssh, what does it mean "ssh otherdns /usr/sbin/rndc reload"?

"the key that's being used here is being offered root write access."
Can anyone also help explain this sentence more detail? Based on my understanding, the key is the public key generated by one server and copied
to otherdns. What does it mean "being offered root write access"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it means to run a command on a remote server.

the syntax is

```
ssh <remote> <cmd>
```

so in your case

```
ssh otherdns /usr/sbin/rndc reload
```

is basically 4 parts:

- `ssh`: run the *ssh* executable
- `otherdns`: is the remote server; it's lacking a *user* information, so the default user (the same as currently logged in; or the one configured in `~/.ssh/config` for this remote machine)
- `/usr/sbin/rndc` is a programm on the remote server to be run
- `reload` is an argument to the program to be run on the remote machine

so in plain words, your command means:

> run the program `/usr/sbin/rndc` with the argument `reload` on the remote machine `otherdns`

Comment: thanks, umlaute, got it. Thanks so much for your detailed explanation. I added one more question. Can you help me take a look at it?

Comment: No, i cannot. If you have multiple questions, please ask multiple (independent) Questions. Don't just update your original one ([so] is a qa site, not a chat)